# How to set the category axis format of a bar chart to vertical?

Tags: java, jasper-reports, reporting, dynamic-reports

I'm using dynamicReports framework to generate a bar chart, the chart is correctly generated but I'want to have verticale category labels ( mine are horizontal) like this :

[image]

this is my code :

```
report().setTemplate(Templates.reportTemplate)
        .columns(itemColumn, quantityColumn, unitPriceColumn)
        .title(Templates.createTitleComponent("BarChart"))
        .summary(cht.barChart()
            .setTitle("Bar chart")
            .setTitleFont(boldFont)
            .setCategory(itemColumn)
            .series(cht.serie(quantityColumn) )
                   .series(cht.serie(unitPriceColumn))
                  .setCategoryAxisFormat(cht.axisFormat().setVerticalTickLabels(true).setLabel("Item")))
                .pageFooter(Templates.footerComponent)
                .setDataSource(createDataSource())
                .show();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use an ChartCustomizer for this task.

```
private class ChartCustomizer implements DRIChartCustomizer, Serializable {  
   public void customize(JFreeChart chart, ReportParameters reportParameters) {  
      CategoryAxis domainAxis = chart.getCategoryPlot().getDomainAxis();  
      domainAxis.setCategoryLabelPositions(CategoryLabelPositions.createUpRotationLabelPositions(Math.PI/2));
   }  
}
```

createUpRotationLabelPositions requires an angle in radiant.

You can use this customizer by adding it to the chart like this:

```
.addCustomizer(new ChartCustomizer())
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public class BarChartReport 
{
public BarChartReport() {
build();
}

private void build() {
    FontBuilder boldFont = stl.fontArialBold().setFontSize(12);
    StyleBuilder boldStyle = stl.style().setFontName("Arial");
    StyleBuilder boldCenteredStyle = stl.style(boldStyle)
            .setHorizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
    StyleBuilder columnTitleStyle = stl.style(boldCenteredStyle)
            .setBorder(stl.pen1Point())
            .setBackgroundColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);

    TextColumnBuilder<String> itemColumn = col.column("Item", "item", type.stringType());
    TextColumnBuilder<Integer> quantityColumn = col.column("Quantity", "quantity", type.integerType());
    TextColumnBuilder<BigDecimal> unitPriceColumn = col.column("Unit price", "unitprice", type.bigDecimalType());
    try {
        report()
                .setColumnTitleStyle(columnTitleStyle)
                .setTemplate(Templates.reportTemplate)
                //  .columns(itemColumn, quantityColumn, unitPriceColumn)
                .title(Templates.createTitleComponent("BarChart"))
                .summary(
                cht.barChart()
                .setTitle("Bar chart")
                .setTitleFont(boldFont)
                .setCategory(itemColumn)
                .addCustomizer(new ChartCustomizer())
                .series(
                cht.serie(quantityColumn), cht.serie(unitPriceColumn)).setShowValues(Boolean.TRUE).setHeight(700)
                .addCustomizer(new ChartCustomizer()))
                .pageFooter(Templates.footerComponent)
                .setDataSource(createDataSource())
                .show();
    } catch (DRException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private JRDataSource createDataSource() {
    DRDataSource dataSource = new DRDataSource("item", "quantity", "unitprice");
    dataSource.add("Tablet", 350, new BigDecimal(300));
    dataSource.add("Laptop", 300, new BigDecimal(2000));
    dataSource.add("Smartphone", 450, new BigDecimal(250));
    return dataSource;
}

private class ChartCustomizer implements DRIChartCustomizer, Serializable {

    public void customize(JFreeChart chart, ReportParameters reportParameters) {

        ValueAxis axis = chart.getCategoryPlot().getRangeAxis();
        TickUnits tickUnits = new TickUnits();

        tickUnits.add(new NumberTickUnit(300)); //sets value with which y-axis gets incremented
        //   axis.setVerticalTickLabels(true);
        axis.setStandardTickUnits(tickUnits);

        //rotate x-axis value to vertical
        CategoryAxis domainAxis = chart.getCategoryPlot().getDomainAxis();
        domainAxis.setCategoryLabelPositions(CategoryLabelPositions.createUpRotationLabelPositions(Math.PI / 2));

        //this is to rotate values on each bar generated
        BarRenderer renderer = (BarRenderer) chart.getCategoryPlot().getRenderer();
        renderer.setShadowPaint(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        renderer.setShadowVisible(true);
        for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
            renderer.setSeriesItemLabelFont(x, new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 10));
            renderer.setSeriesPositiveItemLabelPosition(x,
                    //    new ItemLabelPosition(ItemLabelAnchor.OUTSIDE3, TextAnchor.BOTTOM_LEFT, TextAnchor.BOTTOM_LEFT, -45.0));  
                    new ItemLabelPosition(ItemLabelAnchor.OUTSIDE12, TextAnchor.CENTER, TextAnchor.CENTER, -55.0));


        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    new BarChartReport();
}
```